# Why is date-fns isAfter and isBefore both false?

Tags: reactjs, date-fns

I have my current date as

```
const currentDate = format(new Date(2021, 4, 5), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Which displays
**Current Date is:  2021-05-05**

Then I have `"Manchester's game is ", formatDate('2021-05-04T14:00:00')`

The `formatDate` function is

```
  const formatDate = (date) => {
    return format(new Date(date), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  };
```

Which displays **Manchester's game is  2021-05-04**

When I compare the two times using `isAfter` and `isBefore`, I get false for both.

I am expecting this

```
console.log(isAfter(currentDate, formatDate('2021-05-04T14:00:00')));
```

To log `true`, but it logs `false`!

Why is that?

Comment: Where did you get your `formatDate` from?

Comment: Right, let me update the question to add that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [argument type](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/isAfter) of `isAfter` is `Date | Number`, but you put in string type (your `formatDate` function return string, and `currentDate` is also string), so it will not work.

```
const currentDate = new Date(format(new Date(2021, 4, 5), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
const comparedDate = new Date(format(new Date('2021-05-04T14:00:00'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
console.log(currentDate); // Date type
console.log(comparedDate); // Date type

console.log(isAfter(currentDate, comparedDate)); // True
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I didn't know it had to be the Date type.